# Not getting sound in certain games

Tags: games

So I just installed Ubuntu 16.04LTS on my HP Desktop for the 1st time and everything seemed good. (Aside from being unable to make my resolution change permanent)
But then of course I tried running Hotline Miami, Terraria, and Shadow Warrior 2013 and none of those games produce any sounds. (If I check my sound panel, it shows that there's no sound activity at all from the games)
However, sound works perfectly in Enigma (Though after manually installing a version of LibSDL* to get Firewatch to start a new game), Satellite Reign, Firewatch, Enter the Gungeon, and Retro City Rampage DX.
*And I had to get it on Ubuntu's package site from the web browser since the Ubuntu Software app doesn't seem to have it

Specs
Intel Corei5 2320
8GB RAM
1TB HD
Ubuntu 16.04LTS
EVGA Nvidia GTX 970 4GB
Vizio D50u-D1 4k Display (Though I have Nvidia Drivers running the desktop at 1920x1080)
Nvidia Driver Version 367.57

Comment: Try pulseaudio it helped me with all of my sound issues

Comment: @Peyto I installed Pulseaudio through the terminal but it didn't do anything for the games meationed

Comment: Sorry I meant PulseAudio Volume Control.  I would recommend for this thing only to download from Ubuntu Software, I don't know why but it didn't work for me through terminal... You have to ''mess'' with some of the settings too, but if this doesn't work I can't help you.

Comment: @Peyto I actually did try that too and still no sound for those games, but still I have sound from the other games mentioned plus TF2 and Goat Simulator

Comment: Well good news, it seems like when I updated everything in Ubuntu using a Terminal command and rebooting, it seems like the sound finally works in the other games now:)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue where about 3 - 5 of my 20 installed games had no sound on Ubuntu 18.04.

I followed the advice given by Peyto here and installed PulseAudio Volume Control.

After opening PulseAudio I started my game (Kingdoms and Castles in my case). In the playback tab a new item was listed but it was muted. I clicked the button to toggle muting and I could hear the music from the game!

[image]